# python: subprocess.Popen and postgresql driving me batty

Tags: python, postgresql

A very simple little arrangement:

```
psql = '/usr/bin/psql'
database = 'mydb'
script = 'foo.sql'
p = subprocess.Popen([psql, '-d', database, '-f', script], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
exit = p.returncode
```

But it fails, saying `FATAL: database "user" does not exist` as if it's running under the user `user` and ignoring the `-d` flag.

What gives?

Comment: You don't need `shell=True`

Comment: shoot, that does it, but why?

Comment: when you use shell=True with a list  only psql is run as a shell command, on a side-note you can also use check_output if you just want the output, or check_call if you just want to run the command